# how to move object to an array without changing array property in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I am contracting an array to use it in react-native-searchable-dropdown'. I am trying to push my object into an array using the below code. i am facing issue. Please refer below.

```
let clone=[];
obj={{id:8,name:'Yyff'},{id:8,name:'Yyff'},{id:7,name:'Hsjdb56'},{id:6,name:'Suku'},{id:5,name:'Jira'},{id:4,name:'Suku '},{id:3,name:'Joseph'},{id:2,name:'Rosh'},{id:1,name:'Zulu'}}

let arr=Object.keys(obj);
for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
    clone.push(obj[arr[j]);
  }
```

clone looks like below and clone is also converted into object(This is also a problem).

```
Array [
  "{id:8,name:'Yyff'}",
  "{id:7,name:'Hsjdb56'}",
  "{id:6,name:'Suku'}",
  "{id:5,name:'Jira'}",
  "{id:4,name:'Suku '}",
  "{id:3,name:'Joseph'}",
  "{id:2,name:'Rosh'}",
  "{id:1,name:'Zulu'}"
]
```

**what i am expecting:**

```
clone=[{id:8,name:'Yyff'},{id:8,name:'Yyff'},{id:7,name:'Hsjdb56'},{id:6,name:'Suku'},{id:5,name:'Jira'},{id:4,name:'Suku '},{id:3,name:'Joseph'},{id:2,name:'Rosh'},{id:1,name:'Zulu'}]
```

and clone should **not** be converted to object. SearchableDropdown accepts only array like [{id:1, name:'heat'}].

can anyone please suggest on how to achieve this?. i have tried different ways(like  creating one object at a time and pushing into array, using object.assign, using [...clone, obj[0]]  etc.,). i am not able to achieve what i am expecting.

Comment: How you got the `obj` object ? It is not a valid object

Comment: my initial object is like this 
[{"id":8,"name":"Yyff"},{"id":7,"name":"Hsjdb56"},{"id":6,"name":"Suku"},{"id":5,"name":"Jira"},{"id":4,"name":"Suku "},{"id":3,"name":"Joseph"},{"id":2,"name":"Rosh"},{"id":1,"name":"Zulu"},{}] .. Then i converted into [{id:8,name:'Yyff'}...] in order to use it in Searchabledropdown.  Searchabledropdown expects array like [{id:8,name:'Yyff'}..]

Comment: And, Searchabledropdown is not accepting objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push objects into an array without changing the array property and without converting the array to an object, change couple of lines like below,

```js
let clone = [];
const obj = [
  { id: 8, name: 'Yyff' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Yyff' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Hsjdb56' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Suku' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Jira' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Suku ' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Joseph' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rosh' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Zulu' }
];

for (let j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
  clone.push({ ...obj[j] });
}
```

Try this and let me know , whether it works or not.